# Sharing an image with some text under it, both in the same message

Tags: android, image, text, share

I am looking to add a text message under an image (not printed on  the image) so when I click a share button, the image, and text message to be shared as one message that looks like this:

[image]

My code to share an image looks like this:

```
public void shareImage(View view) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.abcd.myapp", theImage);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image with ..."));
}
```

How can I add the text `Image created by: abcd.com` under the image, (as a text not printed on the image) in the same text message or email etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName));

    //Add this code if you get SecurityException error
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text you want to attach with image.");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet of code should work. We add the image to MediaStore.

```
public void shareImage(View view) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Constant.SHARE_MESSAGE
        + Constant.SHARE_URL);
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.abcd.myapp", theImage);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoURI);
    String url= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), bm, "title", "description");
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image with ..."));
}
```

Comment: why do I need to decode the image file and create bm? Is this printing the text on top of the image? Can we do without this step to create a Bitmap?

Comment: Confirmed working on Android 8 for sharing a simple Bitmap via email. Uri was in the format Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/610")

Answer (score 0):

A simple case of sharing a bitmap to Twitter/Whatsapp/Facebook Messenger was resolved thanks to @Aniruddh Chandratre solution. `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` returns a String in `content://media` format i.e. `content://media/external/images/media/610`

```
val savedImageURI = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
         activity.contentResolver, bitmap, "title", "decription")
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(savedImageURI))
shareIntent.type = "image/*"
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"))
```